# $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1}\left (\frac x {x-1}\right)$

Tags: limits

I understand that this limit should not exist. But I've somehow managed to do something weird to it.

$$
L = \lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\frac{x}{x-1}\bigg)\\
= \lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\frac{x(x-1)}{(x-1)^2}\bigg)
$$
Using L'Hôpital's rule
$$
L = \lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\frac{2(x-\frac{1}{2})}{2(x-1)}\bigg)\\
 = \lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\frac{x-\frac{1}{2}}{x-1}\bigg)\\ 
 = \lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\frac{x}{x-1}\bigg)  - \lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{x-1}\bigg)\\ 
L = L - \lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{x-1}\bigg)\\
\lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\frac{1}{x-1}\bigg) = 0\\
$$

Which does not make sense. Can someone point out where I've gone wrong?

Comment: You can't split a limit across a subtraction unless you know BOTH separated pieces exist.  Here, neither one does.

Comment: You've also assumed $L$ exists at the outset, and argued from there.  This is faulty.

Comment: You cannot assume limit to be $L$ when you haven't proven its existence.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks so much!

Comment: Your penultimate line reads, effectively, infinity = infinity - infinity. This isn't a valid equation to rearrange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake happens when you write

$$L = \lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\frac{2(x-\frac{1}{2})}{2(x-1)}\bigg)$$

because the limit was not yet proven to exist (and, in fact, it does not).

---

You then make another mistake when you write $$\lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\frac{x-\frac{1}{2}}{x-1}\bigg)
 = \lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\frac{x}{x-1}\bigg)  - \lim_{x \to 1} \bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{x-1}\bigg)$$

which is again not true because you haven't yet shown that any of these limits exists.

Comment: The first part is misleading. You can use L'Hôpital to show that something diverges to $\pm \infty$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: @Vincent Sure you can. I didn't say you can't. I just said you can't set a variable to equal to something that may not exist.